# Network configuration with two computers directly connected with ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, lan

I have to configure a network as the following:

`PC1 <-----> AP <:::::> PC2 <-----> PC3`

where: `<--->` is a ethernet cable and `<:::>` is a wireless connection. PC2 and PC3 are directly connected with an ethernet cable. PC1, PC2 and PC3 are computers running Ubuntu 20.04. AP is an access point connected to Internet. I want to connect PC3 to the internet through PC2, and to access PC3 from PC1. In particular I need that all PCs are in the same network and accessible each others. I've tried the option *Shared to other computers* on PC2 and PC3 so that PC3 can access internet through PC2 but this creates a subnet between the two PCs and PC1 can't see PC3 (PC1 has a 192.x.x.x and PC2 and PC3 obtain a 10.x.x.x address on the ethernet interface). Also, after doing this, PC2 is unreachable from PC1 although the wireless IP address of PC2 is in the same subnet.

How could I configure the network to make all PCs visible each other, without modifying the topology?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is bridge the connected interfaces of PC2 and PC3. This allows them to communicate fine and PC3 will be assigned addresses on the desired network.

A similar question was answered on askubuntu, you will probably find this useful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/62027/how-do-i-bridge-network-interfaces